# A Error With Going To Intent Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

```
package com.lazerg.apptask;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class tasks extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        APlusBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                APlubBGotoIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    void APlubBGotoIntent(){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),APlusBClass.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is my code When I'm trying to move other intent Its saying

```
09-01 17:49:22.109 9259-9259/com.lazerg.apptask E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.lazerg.apptask, PID: 9259
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lazerg.apptask/com.lazerg.apptask.tasks}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Put this line Button APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto); after setContentView() and try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Move `Button APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto);` inside `onCreate` before you set the `clicklistener`.

Try this code,

```
public class tasks extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        // Move this line inside onCreate
        Button APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto);

        APlusBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                APlubBGotoIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    void APlubBGotoIntent(){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),APlusBClass.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Button `APlusBButton` below/after the `setContentView()` method.

```
public class tasks extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
    Button APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto);

    APlusBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            APlubBGotoIntent();
        }
    });
}

void APlubBGotoIntent(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),APlusBClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

    APlusBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            APlubBGotoIntent();
        }
    });
}
```

To:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
    APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto);
    APlusBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            APlubBGotoIntent();
        }
    });
}
```

`findViewById` should be called once the `setContentView` is called.

Answer (score 0):

With out

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
```

How you can declare

```
 Button APlusBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplusbgoto);
```

You should declare button after ContentView because with view how you can use widget for that view.

Comment: Good Advice. Thanks